# RichFaces4 vs Web browser compatibility

Tags: internet-explorer, richfaces

Is there a compatibility matrix for RichFaces 4 regarding supported web browsers and different versions of them such as Internet Explorer 6?

Answer (score 1):

A quick [Google search](http://google.com/?q=rich+faces+4+client+requirements) led me to the developer docs, which have [exactly what you need](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-RichFaces_overview.html#sect-Component_Reference-RichFaces_overview-Client_requirements).